# How to Handle Typesetting an Aberrant Footnote

Tags: pdftex, numbering, lists, footnotes

The following MWE is a model for a typesetting problem which I have encountered on a larger scale.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large

\noindent A sentence.\footnote{ordinary numbering} \\
A sentence.\footnote{ordinary numbering} \\
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{A sentence to be strangely footnoted.}}\footnote{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{I want this footnote to be numbered 256}}} \\
A sentence.\footnote{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{I would like to resume the regular footnote numbering here with 3}}} \\
A sentence.\footnote{ordinary numbering} \\
A sentence.\footnote{ordinary numbering} \\
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: In the code, I have presented six footnoted sentences with standard numbering. I need to be able to modify the code so that the 3rd footnote is numbered 256, the 4th footnote is numbered 3, the 5th is numbered 4, and the 6th is numbered 5, and so continuing with the standard numbering  up to 255 if I had presented all 256 footnotes. How may this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using numbers, you can just use `\footnote[256]{...}` to force a footnote to be numbered `256`. The number (passed as the optional parameter to `\footnote`) is used to set the footnote counter.

[image]