# Addendum to the Post "How to Handle Typesetting an Aberrant Footnote"

Tags: pdftex, numbering, lists, footnotes

This question is an addendum to [How to Handle Typesetting an Aberrant Footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619552/how-to-handle-typesetting-an-aberrant-footnote)

I am trying to adapt Werner's answer to the case where within the sequence of enumerated footnotes, I have one which is a "minor footnote" that I don't want numbered; but indicated by, say, an asterisk---with the regular numbering continuing thereafter.

Consider the following (not-yet-working) code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large
\noindent Sentence.\footnote{first major footnote.} \\
Sentence.\footnote{second major footnote.} \\
%\textcolor{red}{Sentence}.\footnote[*]{\textcolor{red}{explanatory comment. I do not want it numbered; but rather indicated by an asterisk.}} \\
Sentence.\footnote{third major footnote.}
\end{document}
```

If I replace the asterisk by, say, the number 140---it works fine; but I get an error when I put an asterisk between the braces---even if I enclose it by dollar signs.

QUESTION: How may I modify the code to display the asterisk symbol as a footnotemark (at an appropriate height) for the "minor" footnote indicated?

Thank you.

Remark: I do not want to use `footmisc` as the document I am working on does not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional argument to `\footnote` should be a number.

Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aberrantfootnote}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}%
  \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Sentence.\footnote{first major footnote.}

Sentence.\footnote{second major footnote.}
\textcolor{red}{Sentence}.\aberrantfootnote{*}{%
  \textcolor{red}{explanatory comment. I do not want it numbered;
  but rather indicated by an asterisk.}}

Sentence.\footnote{third major footnote.}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\@makefnmark` is to avoid a badly raised asterisk. For other symbols you might need to wrap them in `\textsuperscript`.

[image]